# Error when iterating through a member's roles in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

So i'm making a blacklist function for my discord bot, where you basically just put a word and a role, and if someone with that role then... something will happen? Not really sure yet. But when i try to iterate through a member's roles, I get this error:

```
(node:21803) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.member.roles is not iterable
```

Here is my code:

```
for (const word of message.content.split(" ")) {
        for (const role of message.member.roles) {
            console.log(role.name);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly understand what roles you mean, but I suppose you're talking about the Guild Roles. You can get the Guild from the Message, and then it's RoleManager, so you can map its cache to get all the roles inside of it. This is how you do it:

```js
const roles = message.guild.roles.cache.map(role => role);
```

As any other array in Javascript, you can in iterate through it with a forEach loop.

```js
// This log every role in the Guild the message was sent
roles.forEach(role => {
  console.log(role);
});
```

For the user mentioned you can get it through the MessageMentions object. Like that:

```js
// In case you want the User Object
const user = message.mentions.users.first();
// In case you want the GuildMember object (most likely)
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
```

With that, I think you can work with what you're trying to reach. Whatever, if you're talking about a role that was mentioned in the message, you can get it just like the user (from the MessageMentions object).

```js
const role = message.mentions.roles.first();
```

---

As you said, you're not sure about what you're going to do, but if it was like an '*assign user to role*' command, you could do it like that:

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
const role = message.mentions.roles.first();

member.roles.add(role);

// !command @user @role - adds the user to the role
```

Or if this whole time, you were just trying to iterate through the member's role. It works more or less like the first example. There you go:

```js
// In case you want the mentioned user
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
// In case you want the message author user
const member = message.member;

// Map the User Roles
const roles = member.roles.cache.map(role => role);

// Iterate though it =)
roles.forEach(role => {
  console.log(role);
});
```

Useful links:
[Message#guild | discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild)
[Guild#roles | discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=roles)
[RoleManager#cache | discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=cache)

Comment: [`message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) is the equivalent of `message.author`, but it returns a `GuildMember` object.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pass [`GuildMemberRoleManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager) through the [`cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=cache) property if you are using `v12+`

```js
for (const role of message.member.roles.cache) {
   // ...
```

Comment: I tried this: 
**for (const role of message.member.roles.cache) {
  console.log(role.name);
 }**
But doing that console.log(), it just returns undefined?