# How Do I Add Roles via Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm currently creating a bot through Discord.js, and I want someone to be able to state a command in order to gain a role. However, I can't figure this out for the life of me.
In my bot folder, I've created an addrole.js file with the following chunk of code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const roles = message.guild.roles.cache.map((role) => role);
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
const role = message.mentions.roles.first();
const colours = require("../colours.json");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  if (!message.member.hasPermission(["MANAGE_ROLES", "ADMINISTRATOR"]))
    return message.channel.send(
      "Sorry, frog lover! :disappointed: :broken_heart: You don't have permission to perform this command!"
    );

  let rMember =
    message.mentions.members.first ||
    message.guild.members.cache.find((m) => m.user.tag === args[0]) ||
    message.guild.members;
  let role =
    message.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name == args[1]) ||
    message.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.id == args[1]) ||
    message.mentions.roles.first();
  if (!role)
    return message.channel.send(
      "Which role do I give to this user, frog lover? :point_right: :point_left:"
    );

  if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission(["MANAGE_ROLES", "ADMINISTRATOR"]))
    return message.channel.send(
      "Sorry, friend :broken_heart: :shrug: I don't have permission to perform this command!"
    );

  if (rMember.roles.has(role.id)) {
    return message.channel.send(
      `$rMember.displayName), already has this role!`
    );
  } else {
    await rMember.roles.add(role.id).catch((e) => console.log(e.message));
    message.channel.send(
      `The role ${role.name} has been added to ${rMember.displayName}.`
    );
  }

  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor(colours.redlight)
    .setAuthor(`${message.guild.name} Modlogs`, message.guild.iconURL)
    .addField("Moderation:", "Addrole")
    .addField("Mutee:", rMember.user.username)
    .addField("Reason:", reason)
    .addField("Date:", message.createdAt.toLocaleString());

  letsChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(
    (c) => c.name === "beans-the-frog"
  );
  sChannel.send(embedVariable);
};

module.exports.config = {
  name: "addrole",
  description: "Adds a role to a member of the guild!",
  usage: "beans addrole",
  accessableby: "Moderators",
  aliases: ["ar", "roleadd"],
};
```

I followed THIS tutorial to get here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCSbZ2UbriU

I've given my bot the Manage_Roles permission and have attempted to state both "beans addrole (role) (user)" and "beans addrole (user) (role)". I'm expecting him to even specify error messages, or even better yet, add the role. However, he isn't even spitting out error messages, and neither is my console. Everything else works fine, it's just that this particular function won't work. Any input/feedback would help a LOT.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63748081/error-when-iterating-through-a-members-roles-in-discord-js/63748794#63748794) can help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when iterating through a member's roles in discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63748081/error-when-iterating-through-a-members-roles-in-discord-js) It includes information on how to add a role using [`RoleManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager) (`message.member.roles`).

Comment: You also seem to be using v11 code. If you're using discord.js v12 (the latest version), your code won't work. See [this](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html) for info on the breaking changes.

Answer (score 2):

I found a lot of typos inside of your code, and also, it has some problem because you mixed `discord.js^11.x` with `discord.js^12.x`. I fixed your code below, but make sure your bot has the `ADMINISTRATOR` permission as well required by your command.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
// You defined the 3 lines here twice, which requires `message` to be defined.
const colours = require("../colours.json");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  // `Member.hasPermissions()` is deprecated
  if (!message.member.permissions.has(["MANAGE_ROLES", "ADMINISTRATOR"]))
    return message.channel.send(
      "Sorry, frog lover! :disappointed: :broken_heart: You don't have permission to perform this command!"
    );


  let rMember =
    message.mentions.members.first() || // `.first()` is a function.
    message.guild.members.cache.find((m) => m.user.tag === args[0]) ||
    message.guild.members;
  let role =
    message.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name == args[1]) ||
    message.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.id == args[1]) ||
    message.mentions.roles.first();
  if (!role)
    return message.channel.send(
      "Which role do I give to this user, frog lover? :point_right: :point_left:"
    );

  if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission(["MANAGE_ROLES", "ADMINISTRATOR"]))
    return message.channel.send(
      "Sorry, friend :broken_heart: :shrug: I don't have permission to perform this command!"
    );

  if (rMember.roles.has(role.id)) {
    return message.channel.send(
      `$rMember.displayName), already has this role!`
    );
  } else {
    await rMember.roles.add(role.id).catch((e) => console.log(e));
    message.channel.send(
      `The role ${role.name} has been added to ${rMember.displayName}.`
    );
  }

  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(colours.redlight)
    .setAuthor(`${message.guild.name} Modlogs`, message.guild.iconURL())
    .addField("Moderation:", "Addrole")
    .addField("Mute:", rMember.user.username)
    .addField("Reason:", reason)
    .addField("Date:", message.createdAt); // `.toLocaleString()` isn't required, discord automatically coonverts it to string.

  let sChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(
    (c) => c.name === "beans-the-frog"
  );
  sChannel.send(embedVariable);
};

module.exports.config = {
  name: "addrole",
  description: "Adds a role to a member of the guild!",
  usage: "beans addrole",
  accessableby: "Moderators",
  aliases: ["ar", "roleadd"],
};
```

To learn more, try visiting the links below:

- [Discordjs.guide - Guide - Updating from v11 to v12](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html)
- [Discordjs.guide - Guide - Permissions](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#permissions)
- [Discordjs.guide - Guide - Handling Commands](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#command-handling)

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (rMember.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
    return message.channel.send(
        `$rMember.displayName), already has this role!`
    );
} else {
    await rMember.roles.add(role.id).catch((e) => console.log(e));
    message.channel.send(
        `The role ${role.name} has been added to ${rMember.displayName}.`
    );
}
```

I used this snippet to get my bot to add roles. Thanks to user above. I had to add cache though. in first line.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem mainly appears from these lines:-

```
const roles = message.guild.roles.cache.map((role) => role);
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
const role = message.mentions.roles.first();
```

The problem happens because `message` is not defined until you define a function. Try moving the code inside the `run` function.